# How to find only last part of string with brackets using MS SQL

Tags: database, string, substring, brackets, charindex

I have a long string with multiple bracket inside string , i am tried to fetch only last part of the string , But i have achieved first part till end.

```
 Alkyl acrylate-Styrene (or alpha-Methylstyrene) copolymer (Substances not 
 requiring notification is limited to the following: Copolymer of butyl 
 acrylate / styrene (It is limited that the polymer is insoluble in water, acid 
 and alkali, and the content of the components having molecular weight less 
 than 1,000 is 1% or less.))
```

My Query :

```
SELECT  [RigNumSrc],[SubSRC],
case when  CHARINDEX(' (',[SubSRC])<>0  then LEFT ([SubSRC], charindex (' (', 
[SubSRC])-1)  
         when  CHARINDEX(' (',[SubSRC])=0 then [SubSRC] end as [chemnamesrc1]
 ,case when  CHARINDEX(' (',[SubSRC])<>0  then SUBSTRING([SubSRC], 
CHARINDEX(' 
(',[SubSRC]),LEN([SubSRC]))
end as synamesrc1 from xyztable
```

my result :

```
    (or alpha-Methylstyrene) copolymer (Substances not requiring notification 
    is limited to the following: Copolymer of butyl acrylate / styrene (It is 
    limited that the polymer is insoluble in water, acid and alkali, and the 
    content of the components having molecular weight less than 1,000 is 1% 
     or less.))
```

Please help me to find only :

```
 (It is limited that the polymer is insoluble in water, acid 
 and alkali, and the content of the components having molecular weight less 
 than 1,000 is 1% or less.)
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you use something else than SQL Server. String manipulation is not it's forté. Especially considering you want the value of the text that is within parenthesis within parenthesis; this starts to almost create a hierarchical relationship.

Comment: Ok @Larnu i will edit . thank you for the consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY :

```
DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(MAX)='Alkyl acrylate-Styrene (or alpha-Methylstyrene) copolymer (Substances not requiring notification is limited to the following: Copolymer of butyl 
acrylate ( styrene (It is limited that the polymer is insoluble in water, acid and alkali, and the content of the components having molecular weight less than 1,000 is 1% or less.))'

SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(@myString,1) <> ')' THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(RIGHT(@myString , CHARINDEX ('(' ,REVERSE(@myString))),'))',')') END
```

Comment: Starting `(` is missing in output I think!

Comment: @Larnu What final text? it is about `'))'`? If this is not a bad thing, it is only to replace `'))'` if it exists.

Comment: Playing Devil's advocate here, but try the string: `DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(MAX)='Alkyl acrylate-Styrene (or alpha-Methylstyrene) copolymer (Substances not requiring notification is limited to the following: Copolymer of butyl acrylate: (styrene (It is limited that the polymer is insoluble in water (acid and alkali) and the content of the components having molecular weight less than 1,000 is 1% or less.))'`

Comment: @Larnu this case is not included, the question is whether such a case occurs? owner of the post?

Comment: @KillerQueen  i agree above query will work , what if something ends only with ')' other than "))". Do we need to write case statement.

Comment: @KillerQueen thank you . I am trying to get only single bracket at the end.

Comment: the query will work if we are looking for the last `'('` @DataBase

Comment: ya it will work and will take last string with string and end with )) . i am trying to get ). @KillerQueen

Comment: it is working fine . but it is clearing even string :> for Residual oil(kerosene)after extraction of normal paraffin  . The output is (kerosene)after extraction of normal paraffin

Comment: For `Residual oil(kerosene)after extraction of normal paraffin` what should be the output ? @DataBase

Comment: @KillerQueen . output should be null . only when there is bracket at the last in the string it should give output. or  null

Comment: thank you @killer i have tried using case statement and it worked . could you please help me to find remaining word left out other than last bracket

Comment: Sure, I do not know if I understand, give an example of input and output @DataBase

Comment: output 1: Alkyl acrylate-Styrene (or alpha-Methylstyrene) copolymer (Substances not 
 requiring notification is limited to the following: Copolymer of butyl 
 acrylate / styrene    output 2: (It is limited that the polymer is insoluble in water, acid 
 and alkali, and the content of the components having molecular weight less 
 than 1,000 is 1% or less.) @KillerQueen

Comment: `SELECT LEFT(@myString, LEN(@myString) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@myString))),
CASE WHEN RIGHT(@myString,1) <> ')' THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(RIGHT(@myString , CHARINDEX ('(' ,REVERSE(@myString))),'))',')') END ` @DataBase

Comment: Unless you only need this result when the last char is `')'` then SELECT `CASE WHEN RIGHT(@myString,1) <> ')' THEN NULL ELSE LEFT(@myString, LEN(@myString) - CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(@myString))) END,
CASE WHEN RIGHT(@myString,1) <> ')' THEN NULL ELSE REPLACE(RIGHT(@myString , CHARINDEX ('(' ,REVERSE(@myString))),'))',')') 
END`

Comment: @KillerQueen . it is clearing even for Mixture of N,N'-bis(or N,N-bis or N,N,N'-tris or N,N,N',N'-tetrakis[3-(trimethoxysilyl)propyl]ethylenediamine i think we need to put case for this also/

Comment: You need help? @DataBase

Comment: @KillerQueen your genius . How can i thank my best :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help, have nice day :) @DataBase

Comment: please suggest me . how could be master in sql server. Any tip from your end :)

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is practice:) @DataBase

Comment: @KillerQueen could ypu please help me on this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479456/why-data-is-truncated-when-importing-from-xml-to-an-access-database

Comment: Sorry, i was on holiday @DataBase

Comment: @KillerQueen .Ya its ok :)