# Why data is truncated when importing from XML to an Access database

Tags: xml, ms-access, trim

When I import the XML into Access, One of the XML columns is trimmed in Access database. Is there any way to specify the data type  for each
column when importing into Access?

I tried to change the column size but it allows 255 character only but my column in XML is more than 255. I want to copy an XML file to Access database and from Access database to SQL.

Please let me know the method and i have to create two tables from one xml

I have tried using directly importing from xml to sql. i got one link if i click link  one query window will open . Now i have to create two table . could you help me which tag i have used in open XML query.

[image]

Comment: You need to use a Long Text / Memo column.

Comment: ya i even tried with this but still result got trimmed @Andre

Comment: why cant you load the xml directly into sql server?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint i can load . Please help me on this

Comment: @DataBase what I'm saying is cut the ms access middle man and directly put xml into sql server

Comment: @WhatsThePoint . I am trying with your method. but i dont know how it exactly follows. could you please help me on this .i got one row with hyper link if i click that link . Root hyperlink query window willopen

Comment: @Andre  i have edited my query . Please let me know which tag i have to use.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint . i have edited my query . Please let me know which tag i have to use.

Comment: Please add to your question: 1) what are you trying to import? (you have the screenshot, but the actual xml text would be better. 2) how exactly are you importing it? 3) what is the result and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Also: what "link"? And "SQL" is not a system, it's a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya , there is a limitation to MS Access. But there is solution . Let the Access create a table . But create a structure of table by renaming the older one and Now just Append the data to the New one which is having Structure . before that change data type to LONG- Text. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is a limitation to MS Access. I do not believe there is a way to do what you are trying to. Can you not import it directly to SQL Server?

Comment: i can import . but i need all text as that of xml. @greglorious_85

Comment: i got one row with hyper link if i click that link . Root hyperlink query window will open

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838627/import-xml-into-sql-server

Comment: i have edited my query . Please let me know which tag i have to use.

Comment: @ALollz  i think now you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481333/how-to-create-two-tables-using-xml